# Loading kernel modules that were compiled for another kernel failed

Tags: networking, kernel-modules, tunneling

I want to load kernel modules, `ip_gre.ko` and `gre.ko`, on a embedded-device running embedded-linux to make that device to support GRE protocol. Since I do not want to change Embedded-linux device's kernel, I try to **load** kernel modules instead of re-installing device kernel.

Fortunately, I have that device's kernel source code, thus I could compile `ip_gre.ko` and `gre.ko` modules. However, loading modules using `insmod` on the device failed with following messsages:

```
$ insmod gre.ko
insmod: can't insert 'gre.ko': Resource temporarily unavailable
$ insmod ip_gre.ko
ip_gre: Unknown symbol gre_del_protocol
ip_gre: Unknown symbol gre_add_protocol
insmod: can't insert 'ip_gre.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
$ dmesg
GRE over IPv4 demultiplexor drvier
gre: can't add protocol
ip_gre: Unknown symbol gre_del_protocol
ip_gre: Unknown symbol gre_add_protocol
```

My device has enough memeory to load modules (`free` showed 190700/239760 are free).

Could you please let me know why this happens and its possible solutions?

**UPDATE:**

These are differences between `.config` of running kernel (on device) and that of kernel compiled for above two modules.

```
$ diff config_for_running_kernel config_for_kernel_compiled_for_modules
299c299, 301
< # CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX is not set
---
> CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX=m
> CONFIG_NET_IPGRE=m
> CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_BROADCAST=y
963c965
< CONFIG_PPTP=y
---
> CONFIG_PPTP=m
```

Since `CONFIG_PPTP` depends on `CONFIG_NET_IPGRE_DEMUX`, I had to make it as a module to compile the kernel without error message.

Do the differences cause above error messages? If it is, could you let me know how can I solve it...? (and if you have additional references that can teach me about these problems & solutions, I would be very thankful)

Comment: SO the kernel which is booted is the built from the sources which you are using to build the module?

Comment: Yes! FYI, the version of kernel source code I used to compile the modules is 2.6.22.19 and the device's installed kernel version is also 2.6.22.19.

Comment: Are you compiling on the same architecture as the embedded device, same chip? If not, you need to cross compile.

Comment: It's not enough to use the same kernel version: you also need to use sufficiently compatible options. Did you use the same `.config` file? The errors you're getting are consistent with having used incompatible options. Finding the right options isn't always easy if you don't have the running kernel's `.config` somewhere (check `/proc/config.gz`, but it's an optional feature so you may not have it).

Comment: @Gilles I agree that's very probably exactly the issue the OP is facing and I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @Giles: Actually I am not using same `.config` files. I will update `.config` of my running kernel (on the device) and that of kernel I compiled to make the kernel modules. BTW, could you please tell me what are the compatible options or any **references**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by analyzing & modifying kernel module. Analyzing kernel module source code indicates that compatible kernel options should be concerned to load kernel modules as Gilles commented. Loading `gre` kernel module caused the problem because existing `pptp` module uses protocol ID `IPGRE_PROTO` that is equal to `gre` protocol ID. Kernel without `gre` module enabled uses `IPGRE_PROTO` as `pptp` protocol ID.